# Grails 2.3.9: is it possible to set the request format from UrlMappings?

Tags: rest, grails, content-type, url-mapping

I'm looking for a way to force the request format via a URL so that no accept headers/extensions have to be specified.

Something like:

```
//UrlMappings.groovy
"/api/books" (resources: "book", format: "json")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `"/api/books"(resource: "book") { format = "json" }`.

Comment: Yep - that's what I was after. We seemed to have answered at the same time but I'll accept yours if submitted as one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
"/api/books" (resources: 'book') {
    format = "json"
}
```